# checking for a set of values in a vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl-algorithm

I have a set of numbers:

```
{2, 6, 8}
```

I would like to check if *any* of these numbers are in my vector:

```
std::vector<int> myVector;
```

I know that I can check for each individually using algorithm's std::find:

```
auto iter1 = std::find(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), 2);
auto iter2 = std::find(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), 6);
auto iter3 = std::find(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), 8);

if(iter1 != myVector.end() || iter2 != myVector.end() || iter3 != myVector.end())
    std::cout << "A desired value was found in the vector!"
```

In this example, there are only three numbers but the real set of numbers is going to be larger. Also, this seems kind of tedious. Is there a better solution?

Comment: If you have absolutely no further structure in or information about your data, then no (complexity-wise). You have to traverse the entire cross product of search space and data space. Of course you can exit early if you find the result, but for worst case imagine a random collection of data that does not contain any of the search items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`std::find_first_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find_first_of):

```
std::vector<int> myVector = /* something */;
std::vector<int> values = {2, 6, 8};
auto first_found = std::find_first_of(std::begin(myVector), std::end(myVector),
                                      std::begin(values), std::end(values));
if (first_found != std::end(myVector)) {
  // Found one of them!
}
```

Comment: Egggggcelent. Thank you, sir.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if a number is included in a "set", use an `std::set`

```
std::set<int> myset = {3,4,6,34,2,6,78,8,5,0};
if (myset.count(5) > 0) {
   std::cout << "Hooray!" << std::endl;
}
```